# Wireshark and T Shark DNS

Tags: shell, wireshark, tshark

I’m creating a small script to take the output from tshark and print it out to terminal.  I'm trying to to only filter by requests made through the browser address bar.

So when www.facebook.com is loaded, the terminal only prints out facebook.com, rather than fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net etc .. (other DNS requests made through the requested website)

This program loops forever repeating dns requests and writes to the terminal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Would the following work for you?

```
$ tshark -r dns.pcap -T fields -e dns.qry.name -Y "dns.qry.type == 0x0001 and udp.dstport == 53"
www.yahoo.com
```

The display filter (the part after "Y") is to limit the query type to be for A record (you want to avoid CNAME etc) in the request.

`dns.qry.type == 0x0001` is for A record,  `udp.dstport == 53` is for DNS request.

Hope it helps.